# Solving polynominals with complex numbers

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I have been given this question. Where one root is given $z=1+i$
I need to solve for $a$ and $b$ for the polynominal

> $$z^2-aiz+b=0$$

Give that both root are real

P.s i just dont know how to solve this as the Complex conjugate root therom doesent work in this context (there is an $i$ in the coefficient)... is there any other method i should use?

Comment: i have tried that but just managed to get b=b and thus no answer

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about? $$(1+i)^2-ai(1+i)+b=0\to2i-ai+a-b=0$$$$2i-ai=0,\;a-b=0$$

Comment: @Don Thousand i get how you got that but the answer I have been given is $a=2$ and $b=-2$. This is basically the section i dont get if i did that method.

Comment: Do you see the last two equations in my comment? Just stare at them till you get it. (Also, that last equation is supposed to be $a+b$, not $a-b$. Whoops)

Comment: @Don Thousand omg i finally figured it out thanks

Comment: This question can be solved only if $a$ and $b$ are real. You havn't mentioned this.

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc Sure, but it's pretty conventional that if $ai$ is a coefficient to a polynomial, that the variables are expected to be real.

Comment: @Don Thousand I believe that $ z$ is the only variable here while $a$ and $b$ are parameters. More precisely I would say that if $a$ ans $b$ are not mentioned to be real, there will be infinitely many possibilities for the second roo., like in the case of  second solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Just multiply out:

$
(x - z) (x - 1 - i)
  = x^2 - (z + 1 + i) x + z (1 + i) \\
$

You see that $z + 1 + i = a i$ and $z (1 + i) = b$. This is two (complex) linear equations, you get a relation between $z$, $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Since $a$ and $b$ are not given to be real. Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Sub in $z=1+i$
$\to(1+i)^2-ai(1+i)+b=0\to2i-ai+a+b$
$\iff2-a=0$ and $a+b=0$

Answer (score 0):

$$(1+i)^2-2ai(1+i)+b=0\iff a+b=0,-a+2=0$$ or $$a=2,b=-2.$$

The other root is $-1+i$.

Comment: This question can be solved only if $a$ and $b$ are real. This havn't been mentioned in the question or your solution.